# Pass by pointer, memory leak

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers

*NOTE: Initially I though that a section of code was causing a leak but that turned out to be incorrect. Hence the comments below. I have updated the question*

Possible Solution:
I managed to solve this. What I did was move all initializations to the head of the function. Listed them out on a piece of paper and scratched em off as I came across the corresponding delete code. This way
1. I did not miss any deletions
2. Made sure I was not initializing anything inside the loop
Managed to eliminate all but a few bytes of leak.
Updated code: http://sharetext.org/gPJf
The "before" code you can find below:

---

The function in which I am facing errors is this one:
http://sharetext.org/3gq0

From the comments I gather that the initialization and deletion may not be proper. This is the code responsible for the tast

```
float** CMemAlloc::init_2Dfloat(int rows,int cols)
{
    float **a;
    a=new float*[rows];
    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
        a[j]=new float[cols];

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            a[i][j]=0.0;

    return a;

}



void CMemAlloc::del_float(float **a,int rows)
{
    if(a!=NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <rows; i++) {
            delete[] a[i];
            a[i] = NULL;

        }
        delete[] a;
        a=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

}
```

I suspect this function pair is malfunctioning:

```
CCoarseFun::window** CCoarseFun::init_2Dwin(int rows,int cols)
{
    window** a;

    a=new window*[rows];
    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
        a[j]=new window[cols];

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            a[i][j].line_high=0;
            a[i][j].line_low=0;
            a[i][j].pixel_high=0;
            a[i][j].pixel_low=0;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

void CCoarseFun::del_win(window ** a, int rows)
{
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        delete [] a[i];
        a[i] = NULL;
    }
    delete[] a;
    a=NULL;
}
```

Could there be an error here?

NOTE: I have put trace statements at various points and am printing the address of "block". Here is the output: http://sharetext.org/ODSv

What I am currently trying is to remove all initializations from inside loops.

Comment: where are you allocating and releasing memory for matrices?

Comment: There is no "pass by reference" going on here. No memory leak either, at least not in the code you are showing.

Comment: @Naveen - code is just a snippet, appropriate initialization done

Comment: @juanchopanza - Pass by pointer? Im sorry about the terminology, but there is definately a memory leak. Master2 address moves each time function is called

Comment: @eternalDreamer: No, it doesn't, not in the code you ave shown us. Assuming that your variables are initialized properly in your actual code as you say they are, `Master2` is not modified in any way by `mtrxconv_2Dto1D`.  You pass a copy of it and the memory it refers to is read from, never modified in any way.  Even if it were, that could never change the value of `Master2`.  You have a bug somewhere else.

Comment: I concur. The bug is most likely in the code that manages memory or some code that mangles a pointer to an allocated block such that it cannot be freed. None of the posted code code do any of those things, so the bug is not here.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I updated the post to link to the whole code. I will look through it as well. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Ed S - I updated the post to link to the whole code. I will look through it as well. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Per your edit, you have added a lot (and I mean, really, *a lot*) of code.  I am tired, and it is impractical to expect us to wade through all of that.  Try to boil it down to the smallest possible reproducible sample.

Comment: @Ed S - Im sorry. I just wanted to get it all up there. I will try to reduce it to the relevant section. I need some time to do it though. My apologies, I rushed a little too much.

Comment: @eternalDreamer: Is there a chance to run a tool like valgrind (http://valgrind.org/) on your program? That should help you localize memory problems

Comment: It's fine, memory corruption (if that is what's going on) can be a bitch, sometimes hard to track down.  I'll look at it a bit before bed.  Leave those files linked as they may be useful, but try to boil it down a bit.  And definitely what @nyarlathotep suggested.

Comment: As a general rule, when you update a question, *update* it. Remove the bits that were wrong, rewrite the bits that need to be changed *in place*, and add new information where it belongs. Don't just stick at at the end, under an "**Update**" header. The *updated* question should be readable. The original one is irrelevant

Comment: @jalf I am looking to trace the real cause. I will update the question and clean it up as soon as I find out whats wrong. Really.

Comment: We need to see the code for `init_2DFloat` and `del_float`. I'll bet they don't match such that `del_float` releases all the memory `init_2DFloat` allocates.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Restructured question

Comment: Ouch! Double pointers. Try to get rid of them, and to use only single pointer. Always follow the KISS principle (*Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.*)

Comment: @BЈовић - Nice quote. I fully realize its meaning now! But I will have to chalk this one up for experience and keep trying to debug it.

Comment: @eternalDreamer: yeah, it's just a recommendation for the future. I know you already said you were going to update this. :)

Comment: Write your own matrix class that stores its elements all in one std::vector, turn on the debug mode of your standard library and put a couple of asserts in there to catch errors. Sorry to be so blunt, but the code you showed is actually kind of horrible. Appreciate RAII. Make objects manage other resources

Comment: @sellibitze - I really appreciate the honesty. I really want to write productive standard code, not this text book armature pot-pouri. Thanks for the pointers. (No pun Intended)

Comment: Please update the question with the current code.  Remove all of the original code, don't link to it offsite and instead paste it here in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is not with pointers but with references, you are using double pointer to allocate 2D array, and in your code:

```
void CCoarseFun::del_win(window ** a, int rows)
```

`window` is not passed by pointer, it's a pointer that's passed by value

To solve this issue, you just have to pass it by reference,

```
void CCoarseFun::del_win(window ** &a, int rows)
```

And here also ..

```
void CMemAlloc::del_float(float ** &a,int rows)
```

In your code everything goes fine, but when you do `CCoarseFun::del_win(a,rows);` it will de-allocate memory but a won't be nullified, because it's passed in your code as a copy